# Expected loss from using a worker

Tags: probability

Let's suppose I have a worker that checks if a specific component in a car is flawed or not...

The worker's accuracy is 90%. If the component is flawed, he will tell with 90% probability that the component is flawed. Likewise when the component is not flawed.

The probability that the component is flawed is 5%.

Imagine we have 500 cars. For each car that we sell with a flawed component, will lose 500,000\$. For each car that we don't sell, when the component is not flawed, we lose 50,000\$.

What's the expected loss for the company, when we hire this worker?

here's my reasoning:

WF - worker states it's flawed, F - component is flawed.

$P(\bar{WF}|\bar F)=P(WF|F)=0.9$ and $E(L)=500*(P(\bar{WF}|F)*P(F)*500,000+P(WF|\bar F)*P(\bar F)*50,000)$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's correct. You are just calculating the average loss per car and then multiplying by the number of cars. Since the worker's process is i.i.d., your expectation will be as it is.

Comment: The $90\%$ is not consistent with the two $95\%$s

Comment: @Henry My bad! :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a car, the expected loss is
$$E[L]=0\cdot P(\textrm{Sell}\cap \textrm{No flaw})+0\cdot P(\textrm{No Sell}\cap \textrm{Flaw})+\\
+500000\cdot P(\textrm{Sell}\cap\textrm{ Flaw} )+50000\cdot P(\textrm{No sell}\cap \textrm{ No flaw})$$
We find
$$P(\textrm{Sell}\cap\textrm{ Flaw})=P(\textrm{Worker says no flaw}\cap\textrm{Flaw})=\\=P(\textrm{Worker says no flaw}|\textrm{Flaw})P(\textrm{Flaw})=0.1\cdot 0.05$$
$$P(\textrm{No sell}\cap\textrm{No flaw})=P(\textrm{Worker says flaw}\cap\textrm{No 
flaw})=\\=P(\textrm{Worker says flaw}|\textrm{No flaw})P(\textrm{No flaw})=0.1\cdot 0.95$$
For $500$ cars, the result is $500E[L]$.

Comment: You do not seem to have considered the cost from not having the worker and so selling cars with flawed components

Comment: @Henry I think that possibility is outside the scope of the question... I asked for if we hire the worker, then... But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Henry that's true, but I assumed that the worker is always there and he alone decides if it's to be sold or not

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.   I would understand "the expected loss for the company if we hire this worker" as meaning the expected difference in cost between hiring the worker and not hiring the worker

Comment: @Henry I've changed the english to reflect my design. I hope now it's clearer. But if my english still needs to be corrected tell me. ;)

Comment: @Snoop by the way, in one of my first edits, I changed the values of the probabilities.